# How to get the elements surrounding a selected element in a matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix and when I select a element in this matrix, I need to find elements surrounding that element(i.e.top, left, right, bottom).
Below is the code I used to create a 3x3 matrix -

[You can view this](http://jsfiddle.net/6gextpxh/)

```
// declare array of multi dimensions
var arrOfArr = new Array(3);
// or declare as [[],[],[]] as suggested by Elijah

// allocate storage
for (var x = 0; x < arrOfArr.length; x++) {
    arrOfArr[x] = new Array(3);
}

// Populate the array
// first array
arrOfArr[0][0] = "00";
arrOfArr[0][1] = "01";
arrOfArr[0][2] = "02";

// second array
arrOfArr[1][0] = "10";
arrOfArr[1][1] = "11";
arrOfArr[1][2] = "12";

// third array
arrOfArr[2][0] = "20";
arrOfArr[2][1] = "21";
arrOfArr[2][2] = "22";

alert(arrOfArr);
```

If I select an element in this matrix, I need to get top,left,right and bottom element of the selected element. How can I do this

Comment: Well if you selected, say (1,1) the top element would have the same column, but 1 less in the row. Left and right would be same row, different columns, and bottom would be same column, the row below.

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you an object representing the elements around the selected element at `x`, `y` in the matrix `matrix`:

```
function getSurroundingElements(x, y, matrix) {
  var x_limit = matrix.length;
  if (x_limit == 0) return null; //matrix is empty

  var y_limit = matrix[0].length; //Assumes all rows in the matrix are of same length (otherwise, not a matrix, right?)

  return {
    'tl':((x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0)?matrix[x-1][y-1]:null),
    'tc':((y-1 >= 0)?matrix[x][y-1]:null),
    'tr':((x+1 < x_limit && y-1 >= 0)?matrix[x+1][y-1]:null),

    'ml':((x-1 >= 0)?matrix[x-1][y]:null),
    'mr':((x+1 < x_limit)?matrix[x+1][y]:null),

    'bl':((x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < y_limit)?matrix[x-1][y+1]:null),
    'bc':((y+1 < y_limit)?matrix[x][y+1]:null),
    'br':((x+1 < x_limit && y+1 < y_limit)?matrix[x+1][y+1]:null)
  };
}
```

NOTE: `null` is returned if the matrix is empty and `null` is the value set for illegal values (i.e. edge cases) - Thanks to Troy Gizzi for pointing out a complete solution.

Comment: The second `ml` should be `mr`. Also, this doesn't account for edge cases. (Say, that's the first time I've used that phrase and meant it _literally_!)

Comment: @TroyGizzi Thanks for the correction. And, **superb** job in catching that!  I will correct.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a object contains four value, the value in the edge will return undefined.

```
var MAXTRIX_LENGTH = 3;
function select(x, y) {
    var maxIndex = MAXTRIX_LENGTH - 1;
    if (x >= 0 && x <= maxIndex && y >= 0 && y <= maxIndex) {
        return {
            "top": y > 0 ? arrOfArr[x - 1][y] : undefined,
            "bottom": y < maxIndex ? arrOfArr[x + 1][y] : undefined,
            "left": x > 0 ? arrOfArr[x][y - 1] : undefined,
            "right": x < maxIndex ? arrOfArr[x][y + 1] : undefined
        };
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}

var result = select(0, 1);

if (result == undefined) {
    alert("Index over range.")
} else {
    alert("top: " + result.top + " bottom: " + result.bottom + " left: " + result.left + " right: " + result.right);
}
```

Comment: Why did you drop `=` in the return value? And, why are you opposed to corners? ;)  This is also restricted to 3x3 matrices, right?

Comment: sorry that what do you mean by 'drop ='? and .. 3x3 will be modified with variable. 'opposed to corners' he said _I need to get top,left,right and bottom element of the selected element_ so I did not include corner.

Comment: Your `if` statement has `x >= 0`, but the enclosed return drops the `=`.  You also do not return the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right corners around the value.  See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: if x = 0, the left value will be undefined.

Comment: and the asker said '_I need to get top,left,right and bottom element of the selected element_', that is why i did not include the corner value :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please chech my fiddle. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gextpxh/5/)

```
var arrOfArr = new Array(3);
for (var x = 0; x < arrOfArr.length; x++) {
    arrOfArr[x] = new Array(3);
}
arrOfArr[0][0] = "450";
arrOfArr[0][1] = "212";
arrOfArr[0][2] = "102";
// second array
arrOfArr[1][0] = "120";
arrOfArr[1][1] = "1211";
arrOfArr[1][2] = "1112";
// third array
arrOfArr[2][0] = "220";
arrOfArr[2][1] = "2121";
arrOfArr[2][2] = "2222";
$("input[type=submit]").click(function (){
    var selectedVal=($("input[type=text]").val());
    var result="Element not found in matrix";
    //alert( arrOfArr[2][0]==selectedVal);
    ($.each(arrOfArr,function(index,value){
        $.each(value,function(subIndex,subVal){
            if(selectedVal==subVal){
            var leftval = checkNoElement(arrOfArr, index, subIndex-1);
            var rightval=checkNoElement(arrOfArr, index,subIndex+1);
            var upperVal=checkNoElement(arrOfArr, index-1, subIndex);
            var lowerVal=checkNoElement(arrOfArr,index+1, subIndex);
                result=(" Left:"+leftval+ " \n right:" + rightval + " \n Upper:" + upperVal + " \n Lower:" + lowerVal);
            }
          });
    }));
    alert(result)
});

function checkNoElement(element,index1,index2){
var firstChk=element[index1]== undefined ? undefined :"";
    if(firstChk==undefined){
        return "no element"    
    }else{
    return (element[index1][index2]== undefined ? "no element":element[index1][index2]);
    }

}
```

Comment: accroding to the question this for 3X3 matrix